# Making Squares Move?

Tags: javascript, html

I am  trying to make the divs "ySpeed(1)" and "ySpeed(-1)" make myGamePiece move up and down, and eventually, left to right. I made two functions called movePieceUp and movePieceDown. I do not know why the functions are not working correctly. Know a way I can make myGamePiece work correctly?

```js
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 2;
  this.speedY = 2;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.color = color;
  this.update = function() {
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
    random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);

    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }
    randcolor = getRandomColor();
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = randcolor;
      ctx.fillRect(random, random2, 50, 50);
    }
    this.x = random;
    this.y = random2;
    this.width = 50;
    this.height = 50;
    this.color = randcolor;
  }

}


function component2(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 2;
  this.speedY = 2;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 2;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
    this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
    //removed hitting rock bottom because the background and other pieces will be off screen.

  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
      board = 1;
    }
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function startGame() {
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);


  random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);


  square = new component(50, 50, "green", random, random2);
  myGamePiece = new component2(30, 40, "greenhorn.gif", 220, 120);
  enemyPiece2 = new component(50, 50, "Trump1.jpg", random, random2, );
  myGameArea.start();
  return square
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {

    this.canvas.width = 450;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1000);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}



function updateGameArea() {

  myGameArea.clear();
  square.update();
  myGamePiece.update();
  enemyPiece2.update();

}

function movePieceUp() {
  myGamePiece.ySpeed(1);
  myGamePiece.speedY = 2;
}

function movePieceDown() {
  myGamePiece.ySpeed(-1);
  myGamePiece.speedX = 2;
}


document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', startGame);
document.getElementById("ySpeed(1)").addEventListener('click', movePieceUp);
document.getElementById("ySpeed(-1)").addEventListener('click', movePieceDown);
```

```html
<p> Click Start Game to play </p>
<div id="start">Start Game</div>
<div id="hi">Hi</div>


<div id="ySpeed(1)">UP</div>
</p>
<div id="ySpeed(-1)">DOWN</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried running the code, comes up with a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You need to be declaring your myGamePiece variable in a place that makes it accessibly by the functions using it. Either make it 'global' by declaring it outside and before the function calls, or pass the variable to the appropriate functions as a parameter.